# Docker container that compiles and executes file from shared folder

Tags: docker, dockerfile

Basically I want to run a Container that takes the .c file in my directory, compiles it, runs it and exits the container.

```
FROM ubuntu:latest

RUN apt-get update -y
RUN apt-get install -y gcc

WORKDIR /home/

COPY test.c /home/    

RUN gcc start.c

CMD ["./a.out"]
```

This was my previous Dockerfile and it worked when executing with `docker run -it --rm <image name>`. The Problem is that when I change the c file I have to build a new image and run it again and that takes ages. My current approach is this:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
RUN apt-get update -y
RUN apt-get install -y gcc
WORKDIR /home
CMD ["gcc start.c"]
CMD ["./a.out"]
```

I run this with `docker run -it --rm -v ~/Desktop/docker_c:/home <image-name>` but it throws me this error:

```
starting container process caused "exec: \"./a.out\": stat ./a.out: no such file or directory": unknown.
```

The `-v` flag to mount the shared folder is in the run command, so shouldn't the container mount the folder everytime it gets executed?

Thanks for your help !

Comment: What part of the `docker build` sequence is being slow?  I'd expect it all to come from the image cache until you hit the `RUN gcc start.c` line, and you have to recompile the C source no matter what you do.

Comment: The Problem is the `apt-get install gcc` and `apt-get update`, because only the ubuntu image gets cached. But now that I think about it I could also use the gcc image which then gets cached...

Comment: The `apt-get install` lines should get cached too.  What commands are you running to rebuild?

Comment: I run `docker build . -t <image-name>`.